# How can I apply a class to all words in a paragraph tag which are in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

Let's say I have a paragraph defined as

```
<p>Here is a short paragraph of text which has repeating words. Words such <br>
as these will have a span around them which changes a property of words in a <br>
paragraph.
</p>
```

with a script that has an array of words that I want to apply this class to.

```
var blueWords = ["paragraph", "words", "which", "a"];
```

How can I iterate through each item inside the paragraph and append a

```
<span color="blue"></span>
```

around those predefined words in the blueWords array? This may be easily done in jQuery, but I am unsure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What are you hung up on?  You'll basically need to load the contents into a string, split it into an array, and loop through each word, adding the class as needed, then put it all back together and spit it back out . . .

Comment: @ernie `This may be easily done in jQuery, but I am unsure how to go about doing this.`

Comment: For what it's worth, jQuery won't make this much simpler. Text nodes will have to be split anyway.

Comment: @Seth I saw that . . . my point was that it looks like the questioner is asking us to solve their problem, w/o having put in any effort themselves, which the SO community generally frowns upon.  If the question was "Are there any methods to parse strings in jQuery that allow word by word comparisons?" or something, then that statement about jQuery might have been useful, but even then, that's a stretch . . .

Comment: @ernie I release all that, however if the OP doesn't know how to go about it how is he going to Google it? Or try something?

Comment: If the OP can't break the problem down into small parts to try and research, how is providing a whole solution going to help them in the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-jQuery solution:

I added an id called 'test' to your paragraph and created a style called blue.

then...

```
    var ParagraphText = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
    var blueWords = ["paragraph", "words", "which", "a"];

    function MakeWordsBlue(ParagraphText, blueWords) {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < blueWords.length; i++) {
            ParagraphText = ParagraphText.replace(blueWords[i], '<span class="blue">' + blueWords[i] + '</span>')    
        };
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ParagraphText;
    };

    MakeWordsBlue(ParagraphText, blueWords);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the RegExp answers better.  But, a loop will do it also:

```
var blueWords = ["paragraph", "words", "which", "a"],
text = $('#mytext').text().split(' '),
outputStr = "";

for(i=0;i<text.length;i++) {
    if (blueWords.indexOf(text[i]) >= 0) {
        outputStr += '<span class="blue">' + text[i] + '</span> ';
    }
    else outputStr += text[i] + ' ';
}

$('#mytext').html(outputStr);
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/ajK7B/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
$('p').html($('p').html().replace(/(\sparagraph\s|\swords\s|\swhich\s|\sa\s)/ig, '<span style="color: blue">$1</span>'))
```

It's using the replace method with Regex. Regex is a powerful way to make a search in a string.

Comment: Yes. That was to see if the code was working when I was working on. But I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: What if I want to dynamically load an array, and have that array be what helps apply that class? For example, I could make an ajax request and get an array of words which need to be parsed in the way I specified above.